# SLS endpoint of service provider is not called when user is forced logout from onelogin IDP

Tags: onelogin, single-logout

I'm using onelogin java-saml to authenticate users of my app. The SSO part works fine; however, when i use onelogin user administration page to force logout a user, i don't see any request made to my service provider SLS endpoint. Am i missing a configuration to turn on SLO?

Here is my onelogin config:

> onelogin.saml2.strict =  false onelogin.saml2.debug =  true
>
> onelogin.saml2.sp.entityid = https://localhost/zk
>
> onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.url =
>   https://localhost/zk/acs
>
> onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.binding =
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
>
> onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.url = https://localhost/zk/slo
>
> onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.binding =
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
>
> onelogin.saml2.sp.nameidformat =
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
>
> onelogin.saml2.sp.x509cert = #cert provided
>
> onelogin.saml2.idp.entityid = #url provided
>
> onelogin.saml2.idp.single_sign_on_service.url = #url provided
>
> onelogin.saml2.idp.single_sign_on_service.binding =
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
>
> onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.url = #url provided
>
> onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.response.url = #url provided
>
> onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.binding =
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
>
> onelogin.saml2.idp.x509cert = #cert provided
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.nameid_encrypted = false
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.authnrequest_signed = false
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.logoutrequest_signed = false
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.logoutresponse_signed = false
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.want_messages_signed = false
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.want_assertions_signed = false
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.sign_metadata =
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.want_assertions_encrypted = false
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.want_nameid_encrypted = false
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.requested_authncontext =
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.onelogin.saml2.security.requested_authncontextcomparison
>   = exact
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.want_xml_validation = false
>
> onelogin.saml2.security.signature_algorithm =
>   http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
>
> onelogin.saml2.organization.name = SP Java 
>   onelogin.saml2.organization.displayname = SP Java Example
>   onelogin.saml2.organization.url = http://sp.example.com
>   onelogin.saml2.organization.lang =
>
> onelogin.saml2.contacts.technical.given_name = Technical Guy
>   onelogin.saml2.contacts.technical.email_address =
>   technical@example.com onelogin.saml2.contacts.support.given_name =
>   Support Guy onelogin.saml2.contacts.support.email_address =
>   support@@example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, i forgot that i am running the test service provider on localhost so onelogin can't send the SLO resp to SP